# UIView animation is clouding UICollectionView delegate - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, delegates, uicollectionview

Is there any known disfunction between UIView.animateWithDuration and UICollectionView Delegate?

I am having an issue where my UICollectionViewCells are not clickable if I animate UIImageView that serves as a background of my UIViewController (delegate methods such as `shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath` are not called at all)

But if I comment out method call for animating background, cells are clickable, delegate methods are called and everything works fine.

Just to mention, I have a custom UIView class and nib that I load onto my ViewController (UICollectionView is inside this view).

This is my code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    customView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("customView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! CustomView

    customView.frame = childView.bounds
    self.childView.addSubview(customView)
    customView.initialize()

    //self.rotateView()

}


func rotateView() {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(18, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.backgroundImage1.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.backgroundImage1.transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2))
        }) { (finished) -> Void in
            self.rotateView()
    }
}
```

This is custom UIView's initialize() method:

```
func initialize(){
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    collectionView.registerNib(cellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    self.collectionView.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While performing animations, by default, the elements are non-interactable. You can enable it by sending the `.AllowUserInteraction` as a part of options.

Try this :

```
func rotateView() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(18, delay: 0, options: [.CurveLinear,.AllowUserInteration], animations: { () -> Void in
        self.backgroundImage1.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.backgroundImage1.transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2))
        }) { (finished) -> Void in
            self.rotateView()
    }
}
```